# Middleware filter on all my route group except one

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.7, laravel-middleware

I have a problem for activate a middlware on a route group on laravel 5.7.
It's a simple middlware for filter post (centre in my case) which is or not to the logged user .

I activate the middleware on a group of 4 routes (edit, delete, show and destroy) and it's ok for all but not for update. For update nobody can do it.

I have this middlware in Centrepolicy

```
<?php

namespace App\Policies;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Models\Auth\User;
use App\models\Centre;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\HandlesAuthorization;

class CentrePolicy
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;






    public function manage(User $user, Centre $centre)
    {
        if(!Auth::user()->hasRole('administrator')) {
            return $user->id === $centre->user_id;
        }
        return true;

    }
```

My route

```
/*
 * All route names are prefixed with 'admin.auth'.
 */
Route::group([
    'prefix'     => 'auth',
    'as'         => 'auth.',
    'namespace'  => 'Auth',
    'middleware' => ['permission:voir liste centre']
], function () {

    Route::group(['namespace' => 'Centre'], function () {


        Route::get('centres/create', 'CentreController@create')->name('centre.create');
          Route::get('centres', 'CentreController@index')->name('centre.index');
        Route::post('centres/store', 'CentreController@store')->name('centre.store');
    });
        Route::group(['prefix' => 'centres/{centre}', 'namespace' => 'Centre', 'middleware' => ['can:manage,centre']], function () {
       Route::get('/edit', 'CentreController@edit')->name('centre.edit');
        Route::get('/show', 'CentreController@show')->name('centre.show');
            Route::put('/update', 'CentreController@update')->name('centre.update');
        Route::get('/delete', 'CentreController@destroy')->name('centre.destroy');

    });
```

my controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Backend\Auth\Centre;


use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Centre;
use App\Models\Auth\user;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;


class CentreController extends Controller
{


    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index(Guard $auth)
    {
       /// $centres = centre::get()->paginate(5);
        $centres = DB::table('centres')->paginate(10 );
        if(!Auth::user()->hasRole('administrator')) {
            $centres = $auth->user()->centre()->paginate(10);
        }
        return view('backend.centre.index', compact('centres'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        $centre = new Centre;
        return view('backend.centre.createcentre', ['centre' => $centre ]);
      /// return view('backend.centre.createcentre');

    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $centres = new Centre($request->all());
        $centres->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
        $centres->save();

        return redirect()->route('admin.auth.centre.index');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function show(Centre $centre)
    {


        return view('backend.centre.show', compact('centre'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function edit(Centre $centre)
    {


            return view('backend.centre.editcentre', compact('centre'));

    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function update($id, Request $request)
    {

        $centres = Centre::find($id);
        $centres->update($request->all());
        return redirect()->route('admin.auth.centre.index');
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function destroy(Centre $centre)
    {

        $centre->delete();
        return redirect()->route('admin.auth.centre.index');
    }





}
```

And my model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;
use App\Models\Auth\user;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;


class Centre extends Model
{


    protected $fillable = ['titre', 'description', 'enligne', 'user_id', 'capacite', 'slug'];

/*
    public function setSlugAttribute($value)
    {
        if (empty($slug)) {
            $this->attributes['slug'] = str_slug($this->titre);
        }
    }
*/
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
```

My form for edit route is

```
<?php
///dd($centre);

if($centre->id){
    $options = ['method' =>'put', 'route' =>['admin.auth.centre.update', $centre]];
} else {
    $options = ['method' =>'post', 'route' => ['admin.auth.centre.store']];
}

?>


{!! Form::model($centre, $options) !!}
<div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::label('Titre', 'Titre', ['class' => 'control-label']) }}
    {!! Form::text('titre', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::label('description', 'description', ['class' => 'control-label']) }}
    {!! Form::textarea('description', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::label('capacité maximum', 'capacite', ['class' => 'control-label']) }}
    {!! Form::textarea('capacite', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::hidden('enligne', '0') !!}
    {!! Form::checkbox('enligne', '1' , null) !!}

</div>

{!!Form::submit("Envoyer", ['class' => 'btn btn-primary'])!!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

When i arrive on the update page on admin/auth/centres/13/update i'm on a 403 error and in the debug bar i have 3 gate, 2 first are ok and last :

```
success
array:4 [▼
  "ability" => "view backend"
  "result" => true
  "user" => 1
  "arguments" => "[]"
]
success
array:4 [▼
  "ability" => "voir liste centre"
  "result" => true
  "user" => 1
  "arguments" => "[]"
]
error
array:4 [▼
  "ability" => "manage"
  "result" => null
  "user" => 1
  "arguments" => "[0 => 13]"
]
```

I think there is a problem with argument but this route is the same than delete/show/destroy so i don't understand

edit today i try to write the middleware like that :

```
public function manage(User $user, Centre $centre)
    {

        return true;

    }
```

But nothing to do, don't work. What action can desactive this middleware only on the update route because it's active and ok on 3 another routes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is you are trying to access `id` as a first parameter in the function and `Request` as second. The way it is supposed to work with `Laravel` is that, if you need `Request` inside the function, it always must be `first parameter inside the function` and then all the other parameters can follow, if for some reason you don't need `Request` and you don't include it as a `function parameter` then you can use `other parameter as first one`, but as soon as you add `Request` as one of parameters, it needs to be the `first parameter`.

So a simple fix I think would be:

```
...
public function update(Request $request, $id) {
...
```

---

EDIT: After you've updated your answer with showing us how u are sending the `id` of the model yo u are updating, it seems to me you are sending it wrong. It should be something along these lines:

```
...
$options = ['method' =>'put', 'route' => ['admin.auth.centre.update', $centre->id]];
...
```

---

EDIT: Another thing that came to my mind is why are you using `Auth::user()` from inside the `Policy` when you already got the `Authenticated user` within `$user` variable?

Try changing your `if statement` code to this:

```
...
    if(!$user->hasRole('administrator')) {
        return $user->id === $centre->user_id;
    }
...
```

Comment: tried that but don't work. I don't think problem is in controller because when i want to update i don't arrive to the controller. I'm blocked directly by the route middleware.

Comment: We need to see your `permission` middleware then

Comment: Permission middleware is just based on https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission. I added one simple permission which is ['permission:voir liste centre'] and add that in the route

Comment: It is certainly an error in your `middlewares`, my wild guess is that you haven't taken some logical case into consideration with `permissions/roles`, but I can't tell from the code you've given what it is, since everything looks legit, you should debug if the `permissions` and `roles` are correct when you reach `manage` and `centre` middlewares

Comment: i added debug bar/gate result. i think problem is in parameter in the url but don't found why

Comment: Yes that's what I did first but this solution don't work either

Comment: Yes it exist, it's in Centrepolicy, the first file in my post. And it's ok when i use it with delete/show/destroy.

Comment: Yes it's an error. I'm begginer so my code is not optimized. But don't work. It's a big problem. What i don't understand it's why i can use all my route and middleware is ok and not for the update route. It's very strange for me.

Comment: Your `manage` method returns `null` for some reason you need to debug and see whats happening, if you have `before` method in your `Policy` also try to debug and see if it breaks there

Comment: yes i understand but i don't know how to debug that. i think the logic is good but the middleware do his work very bad. It make a good job on another route but not on this one. thanks